# Scala - Nested Iteration (Odersky et al., 2010)

Tags: scala, nested-loops

Following Code is from Odersky et al. (p. 167) on "Programming in Scala".

```
val filesHere = (new java.io.File(".")).listFiles

def fileLines(file: java.io.File) =
   scala.io.Source.fromFile(file).getLines().toList
def grep(pattern: String) = 
   for (
     file <- filesHere
     if file.getName.endsWith(".scala");
     line <- fileLines(file)
     if line.trim.matches(pattern)
 ) println(file +": "+ line.trim)
grep(".*gcd.*")
```

The code will not compile without it because "the Scala compiler will not infer semi-colons while inside parentheses" (ibid, p. 167). **Question 1:** Why is the code not equivalent to:

```
def grep(pattern: String) = 
   for (
     file <- filesHere
     if (file.getName.endsWith(".scala")){
       line <- fileLines(file)
     }
     if line.trim.matches(pattern)
 ) println(file +": "+ line.trim)
grep(".*gcd.*")
```

**Question 2:** Why is the semicolon after the first if condition needed in the code above? What role does it play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for-loop has a couple of [generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_(computer_programming)) and filters:

```
for (
  file <- filesHere                    // generator
  if file.getName.endsWith(".scala");  // filter
  line <- fileLines(file)              // generator
  if line.trim.matches(pattern)        // filter
) println(file + ": " + line.trim)
```

In Scala, generators and corresponding filters can be placed within a `for comprehension`.  This [link](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-for-loop-embedded-if-statements-guards-scala) might give a little more details on the very topic.

As to the semi-colon, it's needed just exactly as the compiler says: `the Scala compiler will not infer semi-colons while inside parentheses`.

Your for-loop is no difference from:

```
for (
  file <- filesHere if file.getName.endsWith(".scala");
  line <- fileLines(file) if line.trim.matches(pattern)
) println(file + ": " + line.trim)
```

Enclosing a code block with braces `{ ... }` allows you to skip the requirement of explicit semi-colons.

Answer (score 2):

Answer to question 1 -

1. A for comprehension should always start with <- in its first statement which creates the context for the remaining expression that are following.
2. All `<-` within for comprehension does `flatMap` expect last one which does `map`. All if does `filter`.

For example

```
for (
    file <- filesHere
    if file.getName.endsWith(".scala")
    contents <- file.getContents
) yield (contents)
```

This is equivalent to `fileHere.flatMap(file).filter(_.endsWith(".scala")).map(_.getContents)`

3. Every `<-` expression should be directly under for comprehension. You can write nested for comprehensions. `line <- fileLines(file)` is not within for comprehension but within if expression. So it won't compile.

Answer to question 2-

Semi-colon is not must for `if` or any expressions in scala

The below code is valid

```
  val filesHere = (new java.io.File(".")).listFiles

  def fileLines(file: java.io.File) =
  scala.io.Source.fromFile(file).getLines().toList

  def grep1(pattern: String) = for {
    file <- filesHere
    if file.getName.endsWith(".scala")
    line <- fileLines(file)
    if line.trim.matches(pattern)
   } println(file +": "+ line.trim)
```

I recommend this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WDaw2yXAa50) . It explains for comprehensions more elegantly.